# How to retrieve permission from Auth0 jwt token using go gin

Tags: go, jwt, auth0, go-gin

I'm learning go and wanted to setup a simple application using auth0.
Using  [their](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/golang/01-authorization#protect-api-endpoints) tutorials I was able to setup a basic authentication for my api endpoints.
Now I wanted to add permission handling using the jwt token.
So I activated RBAC for the api-endpoint and added a permission.
I used the flow from the tutorial for custom claims, but wrote my own middleware with it and adjusted it to work with gin.

```
func NeedsPermission(expectedScope string) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(context *gin.Context) {
        token := context.Request.Context().Value(jwtmiddleware.ContextKey{}).(*validator.ValidatedClaims)

        claims := token.CustomClaims.(*CustomClaims)

        if !claims.HasScope(expectedScope) {
            context.AbortWithStatus(403)
        }
        context.Next()
    }
}
```

problem is that there are no custom claims in the token but only the default: openid, profile and email ones.

this is the token content:

```
{
  "iss": "https://dev-****.us.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "google-oauth2|****",
  "aud": [
    "localhost:3000/books",
    "https://dev-****.us.auth0.com/userinfo"
  ],
  "iat": 1701789297,
  "exp": 1701875697,
  "azp": "***",
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "permissions": [
    "read:books"
  ]
}
```

so it does have a field permissions, but how can I access that using the auth0/go-jwt-middleware or do I have to decode it first somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions is a custom claim, so you need to pass the `WithCustomClaims` option with an implemention of the `validator.CustomClaims` interface.
Then when you create the validator:

```
    ...
    jwtValidator, _ := validator.New(
        keyFunc,
        validator.HS256,
        issuer,
        audience,
        validator.WithCustomClaims(func() validator.CustomClaims {
            return &MyClaims{}
        }),
    )
    mw := jwtmiddleware.New(jwtValidator.ValidateToken)
    ...
```

Where `MyClaims` is something like this. Note your `HasScope` method:

```
type MyClaims struct {
    Permissions    []string `json:"permissions"`
}

func (c *MyClaims) Validate(ctx context.Context) error {
    // Validate structure of permissions here, i.e. check for 400 not 403
    return nil
}

func (c MyClaims) HasScope(requiredPerm string) bool {
    for _, perm := range c.Permissions {
        if perm == requiredPerm {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```